# RSA with ISO/IEC 9796-2 scheme 2 in PKCS11

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa, digital-signature, pkcs#11

Is there a way to create RSA signature with ISO-9796 scheme 2 using PKCS11 interface? I know there is proper mechanism listed among definitions (or at least I think so):
CKM_RSA_9796  0x00000002

But according to [ISO Descrption](http://www.sarm.am/docs/ISO_IEC_9796-2_2002(E)-Character_PDF_document.pdf) schema 2 requires parameters (i.e salt and trailer), which seems to be conflicting with

> 6.1.11    ISO/IEC 9796 RSA The ISO/IEC 9796 RSA mechanism, denoted CKM_RSA_9796, is a mechanism for single-part signatures and
>   verification with and without message recovery based on the RSA
>   public-key cryptosystem and the block formats defined in ISO/IEC 9796
>   and its annex A.
>
> **This mechanism does not have a parameter.**

I tried to create such signature with (PKCS11 exception is thrown) and without parameters (does not seem to be valid) using PKCS11Interop C# class and HSM simulator. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Code I'm using:

```
using (Session session = slot[slotIndex].OpenSession(SessionType.ReadOnly))
                    {
                        session.Login(CKU.CKU_USER, callback.GetPassword());

                        List<ObjectAttribute> objectAttributes = new List<ObjectAttribute>();
                        objectAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_CLASS, CKO.CKO_PRIVATE_KEY));

                        var prm = new Net.Pkcs11Interop.HighLevelAPI.MechanismParams.CkRsaPkcsPssParams(Convert.ToUInt32(CKM.CKM_SHA256), Convert.ToUInt32(CKG.CKG_MGF1_SHA256),Convert.ToUInt32(20));   
                        Mechanism mchanism = new Mechanism(CKM.CKM_RSA_9796,prm);
                        List<ObjectHandle> foundObjects = session.FindAllObjects(objectAttributes);
                        if (foundObjects != null && foundObjects.Count > 0)
                        {
                            signature = session.SignRecover(mchanism, foundObjects[0], result);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new DSException("There was a problem with reading private key from token");
                        }
                        session.Logout();
                    }
```

Exception I'm receiving:

> Method C_SignRecoverInit returned CKR_MECHANISM_PARAM_INVALID

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the exception.

Comment: Hi, to make it more clear I will edit my post with exception and portion of code.

Comment: Specification says that mechanism does not have a parameter. Your code provides parameter to the mechanism. By returning `CKR_MECHANISM_PARAM_INVALID` your PKCS#11 library is telling you should not provide parameter. Try again without parameter.

Comment: Yes, I know that but link I provided (http://www.sarm.am/docs/ISO_IEC_9796-2_2002(E)-Character_PDF_document.pdf) states that ISO-9796-2, Digital signature scheme 2 requires parameters. In section 8.1 Parameters it says about providing Modulus length,Salt length and Trailer field options. I was able to create valid signature using software signature based on BouncyCastle class [Iso9796d2PssSigner](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/94870914/) but I'm still having problem to do it via PKCS#11 interface.

Comment: What makes you think that `CKM_RSA_9796` mechanism represents "Digital signature scheme 2" and not parameterless "Digital signature scheme 1" ?

Comment: Hi, to avoid any confusion - by saying "Digital signature scheme 1" you mean ISO_9796-1, or ISO_9796-2, Digital signature scheme 1? I've read article (https://cryptosense.com/algorithm-choice-in-pkcs11-part-1-rsa-in-v2-20/) which states that _A signature scheme implemented by mechanism CKM_RSA_9796. The latest (3rd, 2010) version of ISO 9796-2 contains three digital signature schemes_. I'm just confused how one Mechanism CKM_RSA_9796 can represent all 3 digital schemes..

Comment: Well [Cryptosense article](https://cryptosense.com/algorithm-choice-in-pkcs11-part-1-rsa-in-v2-20/) says that `CKM_RSA_9796 just pads whatever input it is given front and rear by the ISO-9796 padding blocks, so potentially one could use any of the encoding schemes.` However I am not sure how to correctly prepare the input data for any of the 3 schemes.

Comment: You are right. Is it possible to explain us what steps should be undertaken to create proper RSA signature with ISO-9796 scheme 2 using PKCS11? Maybe you can use some kind of method-mock to describe what should be produce by them? We would really appreciate that.

Comment: Sorry. I've never used `CKM_RSA_9796` myslef and also never seen anyone using it. Maybe you should ask Cryptosense guys. After all, its them who is stating this mechanism could be used with all three encoding schemes.

Comment: Could you try and create a signature without any parameters and a mock input? You can always "decrypt" the signature using the public key and without scheme to see the contents afterwards. @jariq feel free to vote up the question if this intrigues you.

Comment: Hi, thaks for you answer. We were able to produce signature using PKCS#11 without paramers, but it does not seem to valid with signature schema we want to achieve (it's Iso9796-2, scheme 2), which is kind of obvious, since scheme-2 requires parameters and PKCS#11 does not allow to pass them. After some reading I'm starting to belive that PKCS#11 can create signature with partial recovery, but it requires so called "Message representative" as input, instead of message itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, so I finally figured this out, or at least I think so. Turns out that CKM_RSA_9796 mechanism implements old, not very safe RSA_9796 sign mechanism, which requires message to have length < k/2, where k is private key length. So this was something different that I was looking for. According to fgrieu user commenting on StackExchange:

https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24294/how-do-signrecover-and-verifyrecover-work.

there is **NO IMPLEMENTATION of ISO/IEC 9796-2 scheme 2 in PKCS11** at all. I was able to create signature by breaking this process into 2 sub-processes. First one creates MessageRepresentative (as presented in http://www.sarm.am/docs/ISO_IEC_9796-2_2002(E)-Character_PDF_document.pdf) and second one - creating signature using CKM.CKM_RSA_X_509 in PKCS#11 implementation (using MessageRepresentative as input). Hope this will help someone in future.

Thanks for everyone who commented my question.

Comment: Hey, sorry to dig up this thread, but do you, by chance, have any link to what you did to create the signature using PKCS11 ?

Comment: Hi, actualy I'm using pkcs11Interop (https://pkcs11interop.net/) for creating signatures.

Comment: Thank you! I found a solution since, but that'll still help ;)